# gwt maven and javax.validation

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm wondering, even thought I do have gwt, maven and eclipse working together, there is one thing i find extremely weird. The javax.validation dependencies.

For some reason, when ever I import a maven gwt project into eclipse, it will not list the javax jar under "maven dependencies", but rather put them in "target/". Why is this? If i put the dependencies in any non gwt-maven-plugin based project, they will be added to the "maven dependencies" package explorer node, pointing to the jars in my maven repository. But for some reason this doesn't happen when using gwt-maven-plugin

I would like to know whats going on really, is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to m2e-wtp 0.15 may help. It fixes [this bug](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-184) with validation-api-sources and GWT 2.4

Here are the [release notes](https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/02/03/m2eclipse-wtp-0150-new-noteworthy) for v0.15